# Updating canvas in javafx

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-8

I have a javafx application that uses a canvas to render different elements depending on the results of some calculations. I call a render function after those calculations in a while loop, like this:

```
  static void calculateAndRender(/*Args*/){

      while(/*condition*/){

          //Perform some calculations

          //render the results
          render();
     }
 }
```

However, the canvas is only rendered after the while loop ends, without showing the steps in between. The render function works as intended, and I know the problem is not that the loop finishes so fast that I cant see the rendered canvas, it takes some time.

So, the question is, why is the canvas not updated when doing it this way? and how can I do it so it works as I want? I had similar problems using python with gtk and javascript, but in both languages I was able to force the UI update, which, as it seems, can't be done in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are blocking the JavaFX application thread with your loop.
Read the documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm